# Scala RDD mapping

Tags: scala, mapping, rdd

so I have an RDD in scala which is currently stored as a key-value mapping like the following.

```
(A, (B,C,D,E))
```

I was wondering if it was possible to somehow map this to an RDD which stores a key-value mapping like the following

```
(A,B)
(A,C)
(A,D)
(A,E)
```

i.e. is it possible to make the key separately map to everything?

Comment: Sure, you just need a `flatMap`

Comment: How would I go about flat maping this though to separate all the values?

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do it. You can use a flatMapValues(x=>x) to turn all of them into key value pairs rather than one key array value pair.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).